# Nuxt Js: How to pass dynamic parameter in bootstrap-vue tag b-nav-item

Tags: javascript, vue-router, nuxt.js

In nuxt.js i am using bootstrap-vue for the routes.

I can create simple routes by following

```
<b-nav-item to="/licenses" v-if="isAdmin" active>
    <i class="fas fa-id-badge"></i> Licensing
</b-nav-item>
```

But I want following URL.

```
http://localhost:3000/accept-license/N0trTjFISGdLOWxGZ29hZ2h0L2k3UT09/user/NFFEZVZ6ckNoazJOQmdYOXV2dWtXUT09/LV2mi1QDMKmCXn4cNeoOjp1Wx54jtOpI
```

How to create it? Also how to load page file for this routes because nuxt has a structure like below.

```
pages/
    licenses/
    --| view/
    -----| _id.vue
```

Comment: Did you check [Dynamic Nested Routes](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/#dynamic-nested-routes)

Comment: Yes, I have checked. But I am using https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/nav/ so I don't know how to pass in HTML tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by using [Dynamic Nested Routes](https://lnh7n.sse.codesandbox.io/accept-license) in NuxtJs.

URL you want:

```
http://localhost:3000/accept-license/N0trTjFISGdLOWxGZ29hZ2h0L2k3UT09/user/NFFEZVZ6ckNoazJOQmdYOXV2dWtXUT09/LV2mi1QDMKmCXn4cNeoOjp1Wx54jtOpI
```

For the purposes of this answer I am assuming your URL has these parts

```
~/accept-licene/{licenceid}/user/{userid}/{id}
```

This can be represented by the following folder structure in NuxtJs.

```
pages/
  accept-license/
    _licenseid/
      user/
        _userid/
          _id.vue
```

And, then you can use named route in your `b-nav-item` to navigate to that location:

```
<b-nav-item
  :to="{name: 'accept-license-licenseid-user-userid-id', params: {licenseid, userid, id} }">
    Accept License
</b-nav-item>
```

I've  created this [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-glade-lnh7n) to demonstrate this answer.

Comment: Thank you, it is working. I am new to nuxt so I am unaware about this structure.

Comment: I am bit confused about the structure. I want a URL `http://localhost:3000/register/VreCvjSaAJynBIOXLn0h`. For that i created folder structure like `pages->register->_tokenid->index.vue` but it is not working. It doesn't work with random string

Comment: How is your `b-nav-item` that points to this screen look like?

Comment: sthotakura I got it. i was adding wrong structure. I now created` pages->register->_id.vue`. and its working. Thanks for your response sthotakura. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is only a theorical complement to the excelent response from @sthotakura.

Routing has nothing to do with Bootstrap-vue.

The routes logic is managed by nuxt itself using vue-routes under the hood. Here a link to the [official nuxt guide](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/)

Nuxt will create [named routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html) to all the files in page folder. 
The nested routes name is created using the patter : folder names separate with a dash "-"

Avoid use dash "-" in the name of your folders and files inside Pages directory . It dificult the development and can cause bugs. It's better use low dash "_" or cammel case. EX:

```
pages
  index.vue
  licences
    index.vue
    _licence-name
      index.vue
```

will create the named routes:

```
/
licences
licences-licence-name
```

and

```
pages
  index.vue
  licences
    licence
      _name.vue
  licences.vue
```

will create the same named routes